# Traversing a table in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this

```
<table><tbody>
<tr class="row"><td style="display:none">902</td>
  <td>visitas@greenblue.pe<input type="hidden" value="visitas@greenblue.pe" name="email[]"></td>
  <td><input type="input" value="" class="validate" name="nombre[]"></td>
  <td><input type="input" value="" name="empressa[]"></td>
  <td><input type="input" value="" name="paginaWeb[]"></td>
  <td><input type="input" value="" name="telefono[]"></td>
  <td><input type="input" value="" name="cellular[]"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I am trying to create an array using Jquery that holds the name of the input type as the key of the array

```
 var rows = []; 
    $('.row').each(function (i) {
                        var content = {};
                        $(this).find('td').each(function (j, v) {
                            var input = $("input", this),
                                name = input.attr("name").substring(0, input.attr("name").length - 2),
                                value = input.val();
                            content[name] = value;
                        });
                        rows.push(content);
                    });
```

But I am getting error saying that `attr()` is undefined .

Can any one help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first `td` in each row don't have a input `input.attr("name")` will be undefined thus the call to `.substring()` is throwing the error.

```
var rows = [];
$('.row').each(function (i) {
    var content = {};
    $(this).find('td input').each(function (j, v) {
        var input = $(this),
            name = input.attr("name").substring(0, input.attr("name").length - 2),
            value = input.val();
        content[name] = value;
    });
    rows.push(content);
});
```

---

You can also do

```
var rows = $('.row').map(function (i) {
    var content = {};
    $(this).find('td input').each(function (j, v) {
        var name = this.name.replace(/\[\]$/, ''),
            value = this.value;
        content[name] = value;
    });
    return content;
}).get();
```

Comment: @Vikram did you try the attached solutions

Comment: sorry I deleted my comment

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of

```
$(this).find('td').each(function(j, v) {
    var input = $("input", this)
```

do

```
$(this).find('td input').each(function(j, v) {
    var input = $(this)
```

```js
var rows = [];
$('.row').each(function(i) {

  var content = {};
  $(this).find('td input').each(function(j, v) {
    var input = $(this),
      name = input.attr("name").substring(0, input.attr("name").length - 2),
      value = input.val();
    content[name] = value;
    
  });
  rows.push(content);
  console.log(rows);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td style="display:none">902</td>
      <td>visitas@greenblue.pe
        <input type="hidden" value="visitas@greenblue.pe" name="email[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="input" value="" class="validate" name="nombre[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="input" value="" name="empressa[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="input" value="" name="paginaWeb[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="input" value="" name="telefono[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="input" value="" name="cellular[]">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('input')` selects *all* input fields in the entire document instead of restricting the selection to the input inside the cell.

Comment: @Juhana, wow, what a silly mistake. Corrected my answer. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: The output is still an array of five identical objects, which is unlikely what the OP wants.

Comment: @Juhana, thanks yet again. Sorry for my laziness :) updated my answer

Comment: I think the OP wants an array of objects with one element each (`[{ cellular: "" }, { email: "..." }, ... ]`) but hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that there is no input type 'input'.
Secondly you will get an error for the first td that has no input child element. That will cause an exception and the loop breaks.

If you use type='text' and check for the length of input to be greater than 0 before trying to work on its name attribute it will work fine.

Here is a fiddle that will do what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/vtaeht71/

```
var rows = []; 
$('.row').each(function (i, row) {
                    var content = {};
                    $('td', row).each(
                        function (j, td) {
                        var input = $("input", td),
                            name, value;
                            if (input.length > 0) {

                                name = input.attr("name").substring(0, input.attr("name").length - 2),
                                value = input.val();

                                content[name] = value;
                            }
                    });
                    rows.push(content);
                });
```